# How can I set a cookie then redirect using the native http/https modules?

Tags: node.js, http, cookies, http-headers

I can only find examples of doing this using express. I have tried several things, including this:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie': cookie,
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
})
res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/'})
res.end()
```

If I don't try to redirect, then cookie sets normally but the client is left with a blank page. If I try to redirect, then the cookie is NOT SET. I have also tried to respond with an HTML page with an HTML redirect, but then the cookie is NOT SET. The cookie will only set when I do nothing but set the cookie. But then then the user is left with a blank page and has to manually press the refresh page button to see anything.

EDIT: If any additional information is required to help me, then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `setHeader` for the cookie instead of `writeHead`:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie)
res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/'})
res.end()
```